# Androidplot library Put Pie Chart names out

Tags: android, graph, androidplot

i'm using the library Androidplot to draw graphs in my app but i have a problem, the names of the segments of the pie chart are overlapped. Is there any way to put these name out of the circle?

Thanks.-

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you are getting right now, and maybe state what exactly you expect it to be? Does your [actual output look like this](http://androidplot.com/wp-content/gallery/plot-examples/device-2013-04-09-155459.png) ?

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation does not provide this but it's not hard to extend PieRenderer to do what you want.  In your implementation override drawSegment(...) and modify the calculation of  labelOrigin like this:

```
float offset = 200; // radial offset from the center of the segment
PointF labelOrigin = calculateLineEnd(cx, cy, 
    (rad+offset-((rad+offset-donutSizePx)/2)), startAngle + (sweep/2));
```

Applying this to the DemoApp's pie chart example yields this result:
[image]

"s4" is clipped at the top but that's not fault of the code above.

Something else you might consider adding is some logic to determine if the label is to the left, centered on or right of the center of the pie chart and then to left, center or right justify the text accordingly.